# Is there a way to make local Terraform variables sensitive with a Terraform version older than 0.15?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager, secret-manager

I notice Terraform version `0.15` has the sensitive function to make variables sensitive. My sensitive variable is currently being printed to the Terraform Cloud console on runtime. However, I'm using a previous version of Terraform (`0.14.5`) and the sensitive function doesn't exist with this version. I want to do this with the variable defined within a local block like this:

```
password = 
sensitive(jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_val.secret_string)["my_password"])
```

My current code looks like this, because I cannot use the `sensitive()` function:

```
password = 
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_val.secret_string)["my_password"]
```

I know it's possible to have this functionality with other variable types however what is the best way of doing this for `local variables` in version `0.14.5` of Terraform?

Comment: Why not upgrade to 0.15?

Comment: because it's a big code base and introduces a lot of breaking changes which we don't have time to deal with right now!

Answer (score 1):

The ability of dynamically tracking sensitive values derived from other values was a new feature in Terraform v0.15, so there is no way to make use of it in earlier versions of Terraform.